# Python argparse - adding argument depending on existence of other argument

Tags: python-2.7, argparse

I know that it can be solved by `if - else` statement, my question is about native argparse support for this issue.

Let's say my script have two flags:

`--nocreate`  and `--rehydrate`

`--rehydrate` flag is only valid if `--nocreate` flag exists

So

`my_script.py --nocreate` - valid

`my_script.py --nocreate --rehydrate` - valid

`my_script.py --rehydrate` - error, missing `--nocreate` flag

Thanks

Comment: The accepted answer in the 'duplicate' link is exactly what you propose - an `if` test after parsing.  You could implement that action in a custom Action class, but it requires the same logic.  Have you thought about what the  `usage` should look like?  How would you instruct your users?

Comment: If `rehydrate` can't be used without `nocreate`, why not define a new flag `--norehydrate` that means `nocreate and rehydrate`?  Ultimately the goal of `argparse` is to figure out what your user wants, not to tell them how to jump through the right hoops.